# Seeking Advice on VM Drive Transfer within a Ubuntu Guest on a Windows 10 Host

Tags: mount, virtualbox, 21.10, transfer

Windows 10 Host, Ubuntu 21.10 Guest on a VM. Previously was sing Ubuntu 21.04 on another VM for work but the old one's boot sequencer died when I filled the storage. [Since then mostly fixed it but can't expand the size so just made a new one.]

Just jumping up from Hirsute Hippo to Impish Indri. I already have the old virtual drive mounted with the new VM next to the new virtual drive and I can at least access the old drive. What I'd like to do is transfer my old programs, data, and I think I want to bring over my settings. Still deciding on that.

I know a lot can be done by just copying over the old home folder, what else would I need to do? I'd love to be able to just hit the ground running with my old programs but I know at least one I'll have to recompile so I'm more just looking to minimize my drama.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Copying installed applications would be "a bad idea" as there would be library issues almost immediately, which could kill the 21.10 VM as a consequence. Depending on which applications you are trying to move over, it may make more sense to look at the `apt` history log to see what you've installed, install the same applications on the newer VM, then migrate your settings over 

Comment: Figured copying my apt/apt-get history that was a viable option, didn't know it could tank my VM if a straight copy was done poorly. Alright, how do look up those histories?

Comment: The simplest would be to look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` (and the multiple historical log files that were rotated out). Depending on your log rotation schedule, this may not be a complete list, but it'll get you most of the way there. Note that this log file will not include snap installations.

Comment: Don't think I ever did any snap installations that I'm not totally okay with leaving behind anyway. Only possible exception I'm pretty sure will get recreated when I compile something else.

So sounds like I want to go through my apt history log, then copy my home folder over and get to recompiling what needs it.